# find extra key in dict by value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to dicts like this

```
new_ids = {10722774: 5537170, 10722775: 5537171, 10722776: 5537172, 10722777: 5537173, 10722778: 5537174, 10722779: 5537175, 10722780: 5537176, 10722781: 5537177, 10722782: 5537178}

old_ids = {10722773: 5537179, 10722764: 5537170, 10722765: 5537171, 10722766: 5537172, 10722767: 5537173, 10722768: 5537174, 10722769: 5537175, 10722770: 5537176, 10722771: 5537177, 10722772: 5537178}
```

values in them are the same, just `new_ids` have 9 of them and old_ids have 10. how is to find this extra `key` that exists in `new_ids`?

value of `5537179` in old_ids does not exist in `new_ids`, so i need to get a key `10722773`

Comment: The keys aren't the same between the two dicts you're showing. In fact, they have no common keys.

Comment: Create sets from them (which will only contain the keys) and subtract one from the other.

Comment: @AKX fixed, values are the same except 1 that i have to find

Comment: So it's about the _values_?

Comment: @Akk i need to get a key , that is pair for key-value

Comment: To expand on AKX's comment, you're attempting to find the differeing `value` and then return the `key`?

Comment: @Chaban33 You should edit your question to show what the expected result is you want for your data.

Comment: @Chaban33 Pls post your expected output too.

Comment: And new_ids has  9 values,old_ids has 10 values. Not as you state.

Comment: update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First way

##### _1. only key

```
new_ids = {10722774: 5537170, 10722775: 5537171, 10722776: 5537172, 10722777: 5537173, 10722778: 5537174, 10722779: 5537175, 10722780: 5537176, 10722781: 5537177, 10722782: 5537178}

old_ids = {10722773: 5537179, 10722764: 5537170, 10722765: 5537171, 10722766: 5537172, 10722767: 5537173, 10722768: 5537174, 10722769: 5537175, 10722770: 5537176, 10722771: 5537177, 10722772: 5537178}

notLst = [k for k,v in old_ids.items() if v not in new_ids.values()]

print(notLst)
```

OUTPUT

```
[10722773]
```

###### _2. both key and value

```
new_ids = {10722774: 5537170, 10722775: 5537171, 10722776: 5537172, 10722777: 5537173, 10722778: 5537174, 10722779: 5537175, 10722780: 5537176, 10722781: 5537177, 10722782: 5537178}

old_ids = {10722773: 5537179, 10722764: 5537170, 10722765: 5537171, 10722766: 5537172, 10722767: 5537173, 10722768: 5537174, 10722769: 5537175, 10722770: 5537176, 10722771: 5537177, 10722772: 5537178}

notLst = {k:v for k,v in old_ids.items() if v not in new_ids.values()}

print(notLst)
```

Output

```
{10722773: 5537179}
```

---

**There are more ways too. Fastest way also**

### Second Way

You can use a set way too to solve the problem

```
new_ids = {10722774: 5537170, 10722775: 5537171, 10722776: 5537172, 10722777: 5537173, 10722778: 5537174, 10722779: 5537175, 10722780: 5537176, 10722781: 5537177, 10722782: 5537178}

old_ids = {10722773: 5537179, 10722764: 5537170, 10722765: 5537171, 10722766: 5537172, 10722767: 5537173, 10722768: 5537174, 10722769: 5537175, 10722770: 5537176, 10722771: 5537177, 10722772: 5537178}

# n = set.symmetric_difference(set(new_ids.values()),set(old_ids.values()))
n = set(new_ids.values()) ^ set(old_ids.values())

notLst = {k:v for k,v in old_ids.items() if v in n} # both key Value
# notLst = [k for k,v in old_ids.items() if v in n] # Only key

print(notLst)
```

Output

```
{10722773: 5537179} # for both key value
[10722773] # for only key
```

---

### Time difference between my second way and the @AKK way

```
from timeit import timeit

new_ids = {10722774: 5537170, 10722775: 5537171, 10722776: 5537172, 10722777: 5537173, 10722778: 5537174, 10722779: 5537175, 10722780: 5537176, 10722781: 5537177, 10722782: 5537178}

old_ids = {10722773: 5537179, 10722764: 5537170, 10722765: 5537171, 10722766: 5537172, 10722767: 5537173, 10722768: 5537174, 10722769: 5537175, 10722770: 5537176, 10722771: 5537177, 10722772: 5537178}

def myway():
    # n = set.symmetric_difference(set(new_ids.values()),set(old_ids.values()))
    n = set(new_ids.values()) ^ set(old_ids.values())

    notLst = {k:v for k,v in old_ids.items() if v in n} # both key Value
    # notLst = [k for k,v in old_ids.items() if v in n] # Only key

    return notLst


def AKKway():

    flipped_old = {v: k for k, v in old_ids.items()}
    flipped_new = {v: k for k, v in new_ids.items()}
    flipped_combined = flipped_old | flipped_new
    # Find keys that aren't shared between the flipped dicts
    uncommon_keys = set(flipped_old) ^ set(flipped_new)
    # Generate a dict that unflips the key-values containing only the uncommon keys
    uncommon = {flipped_combined[v]: v for v in uncommon_keys}
    return (uncommon)


print("My way",timeit(myway,number=10000))
print("Akk way",timeit(AKKway,number=10000))
```

OUTPUT

```
My way  0.010995300021022558
Akk way 0.028010500012896955
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the clarification:

```
new_ids = {
    10722774: 5537170,
    10722775: 5537171,
    10722776: 5537172,
    10722777: 5537173,
    10722778: 5537174,
    10722779: 5537175,
    10722780: 5537176,
    10722781: 5537177,
    10722782: 5537178,
}
old_ids = {
    10722773: 5537179,
    10722764: 5537170,
    10722765: 5537171,
    10722766: 5537172,
    10722767: 5537173,
    10722768: 5537174,
    10722769: 5537175,
    10722770: 5537176,
    10722771: 5537177,
    10722772: 5537178,
}

# Flip key-value to value-key
flipped_old = {v: k for k, v in old_ids.items()}
flipped_new = {v: k for k, v in new_ids.items()}
flipped_combined = flipped_old | flipped_new
# Find keys that aren't shared between the flipped dicts
uncommon_keys = set(flipped_old) ^ set(flipped_new)
# Generate a dict that unflips the key-values containing only the uncommon keys
uncommon = {flipped_combined[v]: v for v in uncommon_keys}
print(uncommon)
```

prints

```
{10722773: 5537179}
```

Comment: It's also a lot slower if your dicts are large.

Comment: @AKK What About the last way